# C++: Specify child function based on Enum value

Tags: c++

I would like to implement an algorithm to an image, and pass parameters to this algorithm based on the algorithm type.
(For instance, I may want to compute a Mandelbrot set in serial or in parallel, but both implementations take the same arguments).

So, here are the Enum representing a fractal type : 
(I intentionally omit the `#include`, `#pragmas`, ...)

```cpp
enum class FractalType
{
    Mandelbrot,
    SomeOtherFractal
};
```

My abstract `FractalGenerator` class :

```cpp
template <FractalType FT>
class
    FractalGenerator
{
public:
    virtual int computeFractal(Mat m, FractalParameters<FT> *fp) = 0;
};
```

A derived struct for parameters for Mandelbrot `MandelbrotParameters` :

```cpp
struct MandelBrotParameters : FractalParameters<FractalType::Mandelbrot>
{
    /* data */
};
```

And an implementation of this class for Mandelbrot `MandelBrotSerial`:

```cpp
class MandelbrotSerial : public FractalGenerator<FractalType::Mandelbrot>
{
public:
    int computeFractal(Mat m, MandelBrotParameters *fp);
};
```

But the function `MandelbrotSerial::computeFractal` doesn't override its parent abstract function.

How  can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have code call `computeFractal()` without having to be specific to a particular fractal type, you could accomplish that through an abstract, non-templated base-class for your various arguments-classes:

```
struct AbstractFractalParameters
{
   // empty
}

template<typename T> struct FractalParameters<T> : public AbstractFractalParameters
{
    // ...
}

template <FractalType FT> class FractalGenerator
{
public:
   virtual int computeFractal(Mat m, AbstractFractalParameters *fp) = 0;
};

void SomeCallingCode(FractalGenerator * g, Mat m, AbstractFractalParameters * p)
{
   g->computeFractal(m, p);  // works, as long as (p) is pointing to the correct subclass for (g)
}
```

Then your `computeFractal()` implementations can each downcast the `AbstractFractalParameter *` pointer they receive to their expected implementation-specific subclass-type.

Of course doing it this way is a bit dangerous, since you're relying on the calling code to pass a pointer to the correct type of Parameters object; if the caller gets it wrong, you'll have either an error condition to handle (if your `computeFractal()` implementation uses `dynamic_cast<>`) or undefined behavior (if your `computeFractal()` implementation uses `static_cast<>`).

You might be better off just going full-templated code instead, and avoiding virtual methods/runtime-polymorphism entirely.  That does mean all your fractal-type-agnostic code that calls `computeFractal()` will need to be templated as well, though; whether or not that is a problem depends on how much calling code you have and what it does.

For example, note that the `callComputeFractal()` function below demonstrates compile-time polymorphism, in that main() (or anyone) can call it with different generator-types (specified at compile-time) and it will work for any of them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class MandelbrotFractalGenerator;
class OtherFractalGenerator;

template<typename GenType> struct FractalParameters {};

// parameters appropriate for the mandelbrot generator
template<> struct FractalParameters<MandelbrotFractalGenerator>
{
   FractalParameters(float p1, float p2) : mandelParam1(p1), mandelParam2(p2) {/* empty */}

   float mandelParam1;
   float mandelParam2;
};

// parameters appropriate for the other generator
template<> struct FractalParameters<OtherFractalGenerator>
{
   FractalParameters(int p1, int p2) : otherParam1(p1), otherParam2(p2) {/* empty */}

   int otherParam1;
   int otherParam2;
};

class MandelbrotFractalGenerator
{
public:
   MandelbrotFractalGenerator() {/* empty */}

   int computeFractal(const FractalParameters<MandelbrotFractalGenerator> &fp)
   {
      printf("MandelbrotFractalGenerator::computeFractal mandelParam1=%f mandelParam2=%f\n", fp.mandelParam1, fp.mandelParam2);
      return 0;
   }
};

class OtherFractalGenerator
{
public:
   OtherFractalGenerator() {/* empty */}

   int computeFractal(const FractalParameters<OtherFractalGenerator> &fp)
   {
      printf("OtherFractalGenerator::computeFractal otherParam1=%i otherParam2=%i\n", fp.otherParam1, fp.otherParam2);
      return 0;
   }
};

// Example of a generator-type-agnostic templated function that can call methods on any generator-type
template<class FractalGeneratorType>
void callComputeFractal(FractalGeneratorType & generator, const FractalParameters<FractalGeneratorType> & params)
{
   generator.computeFractal(params);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   MandelbrotFractalGenerator mandelbrotGen;
   OtherFractalGenerator otherGen;

   callComputeFractal<>(mandelbrotGen, FractalParameters<MandelbrotFractalGenerator>(1.0f, 2.0f));
   callComputeFractal<>(otherGen, FractalParameters<OtherFractalGenerator>(3, 4));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed, I was wondering if there was a way to check types compatibility at compile-time (i.e. no cast). Looks like there isn't :) 
What do you mean by the last paragraph ? I don't see how.

Comment: I've added some example code to illustrate what I meant in the last paragraph :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! What I was missing was __template__ __specialization__. I however kept the virtual method and specified my parameters as so :  
```cpp 
template <>
struct FractalParameters<FractalType::Mandelbrot>
{
    int i;
};
```
which allow me to do that : 
```cpp
FractalGenerator<FractalType::Mandelbrot> *fg = new MandelbrotSerial;
    FractalParameters<FractalType::Mandelbrot> fractalParameters{.i = 15};
    
    fg->computeFractal(M, &fractalParameters);
```
Thanks again for your time !